# All purpose jQuery AJAX plugin?

Tags: ajax, jquery, post

I'm in the process of writing a sizable web app that contains both a public and admin site. I'm using a lot of jQuery along with ajax and I've run into a bit of a issue.

I find myself duplicating a lot of code when it comes to ajax. For example, one button click can lead to 3-4 separate ajax calls. Each of those calls uses pretty much the same jQuery code.

I'm looking for either a plugin or a js/jQuery function that can handle most, if not all ajax calls. Does anyone here know of such a plugin/function? If so, please do tell.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: I'm confused by what you are looking for in a plugin.  What, exactly, do you want it to do?  What do you mean by "handle AJAX calls"?  Are the jQuery shorthands `$.get`, `$.getJSON`, `$.post`, and `$().load` not good enough?

Answer (score 3):

Simply create a global click handler for common actions and include the data for the request on the tag itself. For example,

```
<a class="loadcontent" href="/page1.html", data-target="#content">Page 1</a>
<a class="loadcontent" href="/page2.html", data-target="#content">Page 2</a>
<a class="loadcontent" href="/page3.html", data-target="#content">Page 3</a>

... somewhere else...
<a class="loadcontent" href="/foo/bar/somepage.html", data-target="#sub-content">Some other page</a>
```

now you can handle them all using one event:

```
$(document).on("click","a.loadcontent",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $( $(this).data("target") ).load(this.href + " " + $(this).data("target"));
});
```

You can do similar consolidations with more advanced actions the same way, allowing you to re-use the same event handler for different areas of your application.

```
<a href="/delete.php" data-entity-type="Person" data-entity-id="7363" class="delete">Delete Person</a>
```

with

```
$(document).on("click","a.delete",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this record?") == false) return;
    var $this = $(this), $data = $this.data();
    $.post(this.href,{entityType: $data.entityType, entityId: $data.entityId},"json")
        .done(function(data){
            if (data.result == "success") {
                $this.closest($data.parentSelector).remove();
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: This is a pretty nice way to keep things neat and simple.

Answer (score 1):

jquery promises help a lot with the ajax callback chaining and improving code reuse and readability. Check out jquery docs for more information (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and http://api.jquery.com/promise/).

Here is an example that may help to explain.

```
        //-----------functions for rendering ajax responses
        function onError(){
           $("#errorMessage").text("opps!");
        }

        function displayInfo(data){
           $("#infoMessage").text(data);
        }

        function displayOtherInfo(data){
           $("#otherInfoMessage").text(data);
        }
        // ---------- end rendering functions ---------------


        //-----------functions for building ajax promises
        function getInfo(){
           buildAjaxPromise("InfoUrl", "data") //returns a promise that gets an ajax response from InfoUrl
             .done(displayInfo) //when the ajax completes call displayInfo
             .fail(onError);    //if something goes wrong call onError
        }

        function getOtherInfo(){
           buildAjaxPromise("OtherInfoUrl", "otherData")  //returns a promise that gets an ajax response from InfoOtherUrl
             .done(displayOtherInfo)  //when the ajax completes call displayInfo
             .fail(onError);          //if something goes wrong call onError
        }
        //-------------- end ajax promises -----------------

        //builds a jquery ajax promise
        function buildAjaxPromise(_url, _data){
           return $.ajax({ url: _url, data: _data, type:"GET", dataType:"json", contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8"});
        }

        //start ajax calls
        getInfo();
        getOtherInfo();
```